# download file from luci web user interface (openWrt Luci)

Tags: lua, openwrt, luci

I want to allow user to download some files using Luci web user interface of my openWrt linux .
I have uploaded my files in /etc and /tmp folders of openWrt.
But i dont know how can i give a url of this uploaded files to user .
Can any one help me ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a symlink to this file in `/www` directory. For example, to download `/etc/passwd` file

```
ln -s /etc/passwd /www/test
```

Then, in your web browser, go to `192.168.1.1/test` to download the file.